# How to add a title bar (within the shell) to any command's output

Tags: linux, terminal

I am using tmux to split the screen into 4 panes, each with their own command running. All 4 commands continue running until I stop them. My problem is that I want to quickly be able to tell which pane is running which server.

I am aware that tmux 2.3 adds a feature similar to what I want [see commit](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/commit/0509be07404a4f4626bbdab56d858f657dc68604), but for one thing I am stuck with tmux 1.9, and I also want to be able to set any pane to have an arbitrary title (or to not have a title), where tmux 2.3 sets the titles based on a template.

What I want is a utility that will display a line of text at the top of the terminal that does not appear to move, while the output of the command I want to run is displayed in the rest of the terminal.

Does something like this exist?

P.S. this is the same question as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/193891/add-a-static-text-layer-bar-in-terminal), but the answer given there is not what I want, since I have multiple terminal panes in one gnome-terminal